# Send form with both triggers for action and onclick

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to connect one button to 2 activities, in this case the form argument "action" and button argument "onclick" inside a form.

The forms "action" is PHP-based class and the button's "onclick" is connected to a javascript.

**Environment:**

The question is generic but to clarify I will use the form in later stage in a Laravel 8 environment. This means that the handling of form "action" is being taken care of by Laravel through a route. The onclick should be triggered and the javascript is physically positioned at the end of the Laravel blade view.

**The problem:**

I noticed that having the button inside the form, runs the form "action", but prevents the button argument "onclick" to trigger the javascript. If put the mentioned button outside of form, then one can trigger the form, and the button outside the form but ends up with need of 2 buttons which break simplifying the user flow.

**Question:**

How can I trigger both form "action" and the javascript function from one button? Note! It is not needed that javascript is being trigger by "onclick" if there are other ways to trigger the javascript.

---

**Test-1: Basic form**

```
<form
  method="post"
  action="/payment-checkout"
>

<button type="button" name="button" onclick="initCheckout()">Send</button>

</form>
```

**Result test-1:**
forms action is being executed, but not javascript.

---

**Test-2: Attempt to solve problem using form attribute "onsubmit":**

```
<form
  id="myForm"
  method="post"
  action="/payment-checkout"
  onsubmit="submitFormFromJavascriptFunction()"
>

<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

</form>

function submitFormFromJavascriptFunction() {
   // Execute this...
  }

 document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {submitFormFromJavascriptFunction()};
```

**Result test-2:**
forms action is being executed, but not javascript.

---

Comment: Your Test 1 can be made to work with answer from Nitheesh and Test 2 can be made to work with my answer, both answers have working snippets

Answer (score 1):

Try to trigger `sumbit` event on a button click manually by using

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

from your `onclick` function

Example

```js
function submitform() {
    console.log('Inside the onclick function');
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" id="myForm">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="submitform()">Submit</button>
</form> 
<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
```

Comment: @Niteesh I updated the question to clarify that the form "actions" is handled by Laravel through route.

Comment: Whatever framework you use for backend, you need to submit your form from a javascript function, right? This is doing the same I hope.

Comment: Will try your suggestion. I need to be able to press a button that issues both form "action" and the javascript, without blocking the execution flow of any of "action" or javascript.

Comment: In my understanding, triggering an action event from a form directly will navigates to an entirely new url, this will make neglect all your javascripit functions, If you try to handle submiit event from the javascript onclick event, this will executes the javascript functions and once that functions are executed, you can call the form submit from the same js function.

Comment: Yes, normally the form will (due to "action") move to another page, but since I wish to stay on same page after "action" I have a code that routes back to origin form. I added your suggestion and the form performs the "action" it seems the javascript is also executed, but only the see the expected graphics in a microsecond then it dissapears. So I think theoretically your suggestion works. I just have to figure out why the expected graphic result is just flashed (the javascript is expected to populate an iframe).

Comment: Isn't the normal behaviour that if having a button in a form, pressing the button will issue the form? Just wondering if the submit procedure from the javascript executes the form a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of doing a conventional html form submit with javascript execution on submit of the form.

The form gets submitted based on the return value of the javascript function.

Javascript function is attached to `onsubmit` event of the `form`.

`button` is a normal `submit` `button` with no event handler attached to itself.

```js
 

//this function getts called on submission of the form via submit button. 
//Its return value dictates whether form will be submitted or not

function checkQuery(){
  var query = document.getElementById('myQuery');
  if(query.value==""){
    alert("Please enter your search query")
    return false; //form will not submit
  }
  return true;//form will get submitted and laravel will see that submit button was pressed
}
```

```html
<form
  method="get"
  action="https://stackoverflow.com/search"  onsubmit="return checkQuery();"
>
<input type="text" id="myQuery" name="q" placeholder="your search query here">
<button type="submit" name="button">Search Now</button>

</form>
```

**Your Test 2 should be like this:**

```
   <form
      id="myForm"
      method="post"
      action="/payment-checkout"
      onsubmit="return submitFormFromJavascriptFunction()"
    >
    
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
    
    </form>
    
    function submitFormFromJavascriptFunction() {
        console.log("submitFormFromJavascriptFunction is getting called");
        return true // or false based on your logic
    }
    
      // no need for below line
     //document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() //{submitFormFromJavascriptFunction()};
```

Comment: The answer does not fit the question, even though I think part of solution could be done by incorporating the forms "onsubmit".

Comment: @Toolbox, for your test 2 you need to updated your `onsubmit` code with reutrn and your function should return `boolean`

Comment: @Toolbox, you can check my updated answer for test 2 part

Comment: Thanks! I start to believe that the problems I encounter is related to flow and my solution, rather then the isolated form. I am not successful when following your instructions about how to solve test2.

Comment: ok @Toolbox , let me know if you need any specific explanation. I shall try to provide answers.

Comment: Will do some test outside the framwork I am using, in order to see if your suggestions work there.